# Is it possible to share Minecraft texture pack on iPad through family sharing?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My children play to Minecraft on their iPad mini. My son has bought a texture pack. Is it possible to share it with other members of the family through family sharing like we do generally for purchased apps? Or do I need to buy the texture pack on each iPad? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use family sharing to share in-app purchases, including texture packs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign in with the account that bought the texture pack and then tap restore purchases to get the texture pack.

Comment: They're not asking about how to get it; they're asking how to get it across multiple accounts.